# Music Library Sorting

Tags: music-player, sort

I've tried a few different music players and they all seem to lack the one feature I want. It's possible they all have it and I just don't know how to use it, too. I've got a collection that's only about 5,000 songs and every app I've tried wants to sort by artist, but it also likes to add EVERY. ARTIST. ON. THE. SONG. I hate that. I want to sort by album artist. What app does this?

I want to be able to find Dr. Dre The Chronic, by filtering by Dr. Dre.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, Rhythmbox have that. Which music players did you tried? [Clementine](https://clementine-player.org) have that.